# JQuery insertBefore() isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that I made with a sliding navigation bar. When closed it only displays the icons. Unfortunately, since WordPress dynamically does the menu, there is no way I can hard code the icons in. So my solution was to use JQuery and use the insertBefore function to insert a piece of html code before the link tag. I made the code, uploaded it, and nothing happens. The console doesn't output an error either so I'm entirely sure whats wrong.

main.js

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            $("<i class='fa fa-comment fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($('<a href="http://richmun.com/sample-page/">Conference</a>'));
            console.log("Inserted!")
            $("<i class='fa fa-question-circle fa-lg'>").insertBefore($(".about"));
            $("<i class='fa fa-users fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($(".staff"));
            $("<i class='fa fa-globe fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($(".committees"));
            $("<i class='fa fa-envelope fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($(".contact"));
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Link to the website.](http://www.richmun.com)

Comment: `.insertBefore($(".about"))` should read `.insertBefore(".about")` http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: Well I would never imagine that you meant `$(document).keydown(function (e) {`.
It works for me if I press any key, long time.

Comment: OH Jeez. I can't believe I didn't see the keydown.. I made this in the middle of the night.. Thanks!!

Comment: I wrote you an answer for it! good luck savioa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to bind it to "keydown" event?

Have you tried without it, just like:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("<i class='fa fa-comment fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($('<a href="http://richmun.com/sample-page/">Conference</a>'));
        console.log("Inserted!")
        $("<i class='fa fa-question-circle fa-lg'>").insertBefore($(".about"));
        $("<i class='fa fa-users fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($(".staff"));
        $("<i class='fa fa-globe fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($(".committees"));
        $("<i class='fa fa-envelope fa-lg'></i>").insertBefore($(".contact"));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove $(document).keydown(function(e){

}

Which create your menu only after hard press on any key.

**[I wonder what jQuery.keydown Does](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)**

Good luck! I hope it helps!